# Golang slice append built-in function returning value

Tags: go, slice

The return value of slice2 of this code is [[1 1][1 1]].
And that got me confuse because I was expecting [[0 0][1 1]].
I can't figure it out why is returning [[1 1][1 1]] and not [[0 0][1 1]].
I would appreciate if someone can explain that. Thanks.

```
slice := []int{0, 0}
slice2 := [][]int{}

for i := range slice {
    slice[0] = i
    slice[1] = i
    slice2 = append(slice2, slice)
}
fmt.Println(slice2)
```

You can check the code in this link
[play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/6wX4CO5d_o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals#TOC_4.)

In your case your are appending a slice(pointer) not the slice's values. To get the desired result you have to declare a new slice in each iteration and append the new slice to slice2.

```
func main() {
    slice := []int{0, 0}
    slice2 := [][]int{}

    for i := range slice {
        ns := []int{0, 0}
        ns[0] = i
        ns[1] = i
        slice2 = append(slice2, ns)
    }
    fmt.Println(slice2) // Outputs: [[0 0] [1 1]]
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oogUDjj452)

Answer (score 1):

When you range over the slice, it is not giving you the VALUES of the slice, it is giving you the indexes. This for loop is equivalent to `for i:=0; i < len(slice); i++ {}`. So by the time it gets through iteration, both values are in `slice` are 1, and you have appended it to `slice2` twice.

If you wanted the values of the slice, you would need to do `for i, v := range slice {}` which would give you both the indexes and the values. You could use `_` in place of `i` if you didn't want the index.

Also note that appending `slice` twice like this appends the same exact slice because slices are allocated as pointers on the heap and it is therefore a pointer to the slice. Thus `slice2[0] == slice2[1]` because it is the same exact slice.

Comment: Specifically, a `slice` is a structure with 3 fields: a pointer to an underlying array, a capacity, and a length.  Since you're updating the items of the slice by index, you're altering the underlying array.  Since you're appending the same slice twice, both refer to the same underlying array, so altering the values in the second loop iteration alters what the first slice has as values as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you append to `slice2` is **a reference** to `slice`, not the values contained in `slice` at the time of the call.

This means that at the end, `slice2` contains two pointers to the same slice. Any changes to the `slice` variable will be reflected to `slice2` and vice-versa: they point to the same location in memory.

As a proof, just do:

```
slice2[0][1] = 2
fmt.Println(slice2)
fmt.Println(slice)
```

You will get:

```
[[1 2] [1 2]]
[1 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now everything make sense.